# Поиск по MySQL - найти слово

Tags: mysql

Вот запрос для поиска по MySQL:

```
SELECT `opisanie` FROM `daba` where vepe='все'
```

Он выводит информация из поля "opisanie" в БД "daba", если таблица "vepe" содержит "все". Но он ничего не находит, если, к примеру, в таблице "vepe" будет написано: "Товары все".

Как сделать так, чтобы он находил "все" в не зависимости от того, что будет написано до этого слова?

Comment: Поиск идёт по **полю** таблицы.<br>
`daba` - таблица<br>
`opisanie` и `vepe` - поля таблицы `daba`

Comment: Да, оговорился, daba - таблица, а не название бд...
В общем все понял, надо использовать %.

Comment: Не просто % а совместно с оператором LIKE ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых к БД ты уже подключился и писать больше её никуда не нужно.
Во-вторых

```
SELECT `opisanie` FROM `daba` where 'vepe'='все'
```

'название таблицы'='все' найдёт только четкое соответствие!

А если хочешь найти по вхождению, то напиши так '%текст' найдет все где встречается 'что-то и слово все'

```
SELECT `opisanie` FROM `daba` where 'vepe' LIKE '%все'
```

**//UPD** ну тогда LIKE юзай

Comment: Подправил, сори на работе сижу, запыхался. Минус можно и убрать.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то лучше: ...LIKE '% все'

Comment: Мне кажется корректнее написать `\`vepe\` LIKE '%все'`, если написать `'vepe' LIKE '%все'`, то `vepe` воспримется как строка, а не поле.